# How to make a 3D object array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
lyricsInp = document.getElementById("lyrics").value;
var lines = lyricsInp.split("\n");
for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    holder[0][i] = new Array();
    words = lines[i].replace(/[ \t\r]+/g, "###").split("###");
    for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        holder[0][i][j].word = words[j];
        holder[0][i][j].startT = 0;
        holder[0][i][j].endT = 0;
    }
}
```

Here I need each holder element to keep `word,` `startT` and `endT`, but this does not work. How do I make this happen.

Comment: What is `holder[0]`? What does not work? Code seems fine (unless some uneccessary global variables)

Comment: Try `['word']` instead of `.word` ... or use a javascript object instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `holder[0][i][j]` as an object literal:

```
for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
    holder[0][i][j] = {};

    holder[0][i][j].word = words[j];
    holder[0][i][j].startT = 0;
    holder[0][i][j].endT = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lyricsInp =  document.getElementById("lyrics").value;
var lines = lyricsInp.split("\n");
for (i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
    holder[0][i] = new Array();
    words = lines[i].replace(/[ \t\r]+/g,"###").split("###");
    for (j=0;j<words.length;j++){
        holder[0][i][j] = {
                word: words[j],
                startT: 0,
                endT: 0
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var holder = [[]];

var lyricsInp = document.getElementById("lyrics").value,
    lines = lyricsInp.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    holder[0][i] = [];
    var words = lines[i].replace(/[ \t\r]+/g, "###").split("###");
    for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        holder[0][i][j] = {
            word: words[j],
            startT: 0,
            endT: 0
        };
    }
}
```